# Please advise on applying US B2 visa from Dubai to accompany my husband traveling to US for business meetings (working in Italy)?

Tags: usa, visa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian national working in Dubai staying with my parents in Dubai. I am recently married and my husband works in Europe (Indian national). He travels frequently to US for business meetings. I wanted to accompany him and am applying for B2 visitor visa from Dubai.

Will it be a problem while applying for visa that I am working in Dubai and my husband in europe?
Please advise in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem, but it shouldn't be a big problem nor an insurmountable one.  It could make it more burdensome for you to come up with the documents you need to establish your story, because some of those documents will be your husband's, and he is in a different country.  But the fact that you live apart from your husband probably works in your favor by showing the strength of your commitment to your employment and your parents.

Good luck with the visa application and with your trip to the US.